# Does \setstretch{2} truly give double spacing exactly like Ms Word when using the set space package?

Tags: setspace

I have read previous posts about how `\doublespacing`is not precisely the double spacing achieved in MS Word. Thus, to truly achieve the same double spacing as word, we need to use `\setstretch{2}`. However, as shown in the image below, this is not true. When using `\setstretch{2}`, the line spacing in LaTeX is noticeably larger than the double spacing in MS Word. The left PDF is LaTeX while the right is MS Word. I know this is being "too particular", but my teacher has a strict requirement and noticed that my spacing is off.

[image]

Comment: Just fine-tune the number until there is the same number of lines on each page.  We don't know how MS Word interprets the line space; Word is not FOSS.  I doubt Word is consistent over versions.

Comment: There is no precise definition of what “double spacing” means, unless you're talking about typewriters. And your teacher is wrong: wide spacing hinders readability. But don't tell her/him. ;-)